# Make text appear on hover

Tags: html, css, text, hover

So I need the text to appear on hover over the image (it doesnt have to be a link if that is too difficult)

html

```
<div id="con">
    <div id="box1">
        <p id="text1">
            <a href="url">DESTINATION</a>SS
        </p>
    </div>
```

css

```
#con {
width:1024px;
height:670px;
background-color: #161717;
}

#box1 {
float:left;
font-size:25px;
width:388px;
height:477px;
background-image: url(media/trying1.png);
margin-left: 120px;
margin-top: 90px;

}
```

Comment: http://opax.swin.edu.au/~9991042/DDM10001/brief_2/Amalfi%20Coast/www_root/

Comment: How do you want the text to appear? A popup? Clickable text? What text should appear? What image are you talking about? Use terms such as "when you hover the #box1 div...". But first and foremost, create a jsFiddle for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#con {
width:1024px;
height:670px;
background-color: #161717;
}

#box1 {
float:left;
font-size:25px;
width:388px;
height:477px;
background-image: url(media/trying1.png);
background: #ccc; /*for example*/
margin-left: 120px;
margin-top: 90px;
    
}

#text1{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#box1:hover #text1{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
<div id="box1">
<p id="text1">
<a href="url">DESTINATION</a>SS
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple css

```
#box1 > #text1 {
    display: none;
}

#box1:hover > #text1 {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```css
#con {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 670px;
  background-color: #161717;
}
#box1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 388px;
  height: 477px;
  /* Changed the background url so that it works */
  background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}
/* The CSS below is added to hopefully achieve the effect you're looking for. */

#text1 {
  display: none;
}
#box1:hover #text1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
  <div id="box1">
    <p id="text1">
      <a href="url">DESTINATION</a>SS
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
#box1 a{display:none;}
#box1:hover a{display:inline;}
```

[link here](http://jsfiddle.net/d34ozf1k/)

or if you want this for `<p>`

```
#box1 #text1{display:none;}
#box1:hover #text1{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
<style>
#con {
width:1024px;
height:670px;
background-color: #161717;

}

#box1 {
float:left;
font-size:25px;
width:388px;
height:477px;
background-image: url(media/trying1.png);
margin-left: 120px;
margin-top: 90px;
color:#161717;



}
#con:hover #box1 {

color:white;

}

</style>
```

what you can do is to detect when parent is hover but the css effect is for the child

hope this can help